# Laravel 4 Eloquent group by relationship date

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

I have a topics and links tables on Laravel 4.2 with Eloquent ORM. They have a relationship like this;

Topic model:

```
class Topic extends \Eloquent {
    public function links()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('Link');
    }
}
```

Link model:

```
class Link extends \Eloquent {
    public function topics()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('Topic');
    }
}
```

I want to group links like this;

**05.02.2015**

First Topic

1. Sample link
2. Sample link

Second Topic

1. Sample link
2. Sample link

**04.02.2015**

First Topic

1. Sample link
2. Sample link

Second Topic

1. Sample link
2. Sample link

**Database scheme**

topics

- id
- name
- created_at
- updated_at

links

- id
- title
- created_at
- updated_at

link_topic

- id
- link_id
- topic_id

How can I do this? I didn't solve this problem.

Thanks.

Comment: What fields are on your database tables? Can you give us some sample rows?

Comment: Added database scheme.

Answer (score -2):

I think you should use something like this...

```
Topic::with(['links' => function($query){
    $query->orderBy('created_at', 'DESC');
}])->all();
```

Comment: I want to group by date like I give sample.

Comment: You can't do group by date direcly from this point of view, you will need to use array_where.